# Android Java provide custom host name to IP resolution

Tags: java, android, curl, dns

Is there a way to provide a custom host name to IP resolution in Java/Android like CURL does with the [CURLOPT_RESOLVE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RESOLVE.html) property?

Comment: What do you mean with "custom"? Like circumvent DNS lookup? Or just **add** a lookup that is unknown to DNS. Googling this I found you can edit your /etc/hosts using ADB. I would be disappointed if you could do this programmatically through a non-root App, though.

Comment: Yes, adding a lookup unknown by the DNS. Maybe by adding a system property os something like that. I found these properties here, but they don't seem to provide this possibility: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html
Modifying the hosts file is not an option for non rooted phones...

Comment: Java 8 Technotes do not necessarily apply to Android.

Comment: Well, name to IP lookup is configured through the `hosts` file (apart from DNS service of course). What are you actually trying to do there? Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: Just wanted to know if there was the possibility to provide the host name resolution in the app itself. The host name should be kept on the SNI and HTTPS request.